# HornetQ embedded: can I set paging options for dynamic addreses?

Tags: java, hornetq

I'm using HornetQ in an embedded configuration with the Configuration object itself created programatically. The application supports dynamic address creation.

I'd like to be able to set certain options when new addresses are created: page file use, maximum page file size, memory threshold for paging. According to [the HornetQ documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.2.Final/user-manual/en/html/paging.html), this needs to be done per-address.

I've tried updating my configuration object with the settings for the new address, but the server (which has already been started) does not use these new settings.

Is there a way to tell the server about per-address settings once it has started?

Alternatively, can I tell the server to automatically page for *all* addresses before I start it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found the answer shortly after posting: you can use the paging manager for the embedded server:

```
final AddressSettings addressSetting = new AddressSettings();
addressSetting.setMaxSizeBytes(10 * 1024 * 1024); // 10 MB
addressSetting.setPageSizeBytes(1024 * 1024);     // 1 MB

server.getPagingManager().getPageStore(new SimpleString(addressName))
                         .applySetting(addressSetting);
```

Alternatively the settings for *all* addresses can be set on the configuration object (based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941449)):

```
final Configuration hornetConfig = new ConfigurationImpl();
// other configuration...

final AddressSettings addressSetting = new AddressSettings();
addressSetting.setMaxSizeBytes(10 * 1024 * 1024); // 10 MB
addressSetting.setPageSizeBytes(1024 * 1024);     // 1 MB

final Map<String, AddressSettings> addressing = new HashMap<String, AddressSettings>();
addressing.put("#", addressSetting); // the # pattern matches all addresses
hornetConfig.setAddressesSettings(addressing);
```